# Mock return value of a function for one case input, otherwise return original value

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

**apps.my_module.py**

```py
def my_func(name: str) -> str:
    if name == 'a':
        return 'name is a'
    elif name == 'b':
        return 'name is b'
    else:
        return 'not defined'
```

I want to mock `my_func` in ***tests.py***
the mocked function return value for `a` is `name is AA` not `name is a`, but the return value for `b` and else must stay the same

I want to do this using `unittest`, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution goes as the following:

in ***tests.py***

```py
from apps import my_module
import unitteest

class test(unittest.TestCase):
    def any_test(self, *_):
        original_func = my_module.my_func
        def mocked_func(name):
            if name == 'a':
                return 'name is AA'
            else:
                return original_func(name)
```

Comment: `orignial_func = my_module.my_func`. This isn't that tricky; you're simply wrapping the original function in a new function that examines the argument to decide whether or not to call the original function.